# Publishing stuck at waiting for deployment SDL Web 8.5

Tags: web8.5, deployer, deployer-conf

Recently I installed SDL Web 8.5 (CMS and CD in a single machine), I followed the [SDL Live Content Documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-8789A353-267D-4466-9A6D-4CF6709E4E88) to perform an installation on a single machine. Everything went smooth, but when I am trying to publish any page, it's getting stuck at **Waiting for deployment** and finally the publishing fails at **preparing deployment** with below error;

> Polling for notification for destination: GoQF2fif6ZH5scB15oh6rA== has exceeded polling attempts for transaction: tcm:0-2006-66560

*I am unable to find out the reason why publishing is stuck.*

- Deployer service is up and running
- `http://localhost:8084/httpupload` is up and running
- Below is the deployer config detail;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Deployer xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="8.5" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/deployer-conf.xsd">
    <Pipelines>
        <Pipeline Id="Tridion-Bootstrap" Action="TridionBootstrap" Verb="Content,Prepare,Commit">
            <Steps>
                <Step Id="TridionUnzipStep"/>
            </Steps>
        </Pipeline>
        <Pipeline Id="Tridion-Wait" Action="Deploy,Undeploy" Verb="Wait">
            <Steps>
                <Step Id="TridionWaitStep"/>
            </Steps>
        </Pipeline>
        <Pipeline Id="Tridion-Process-Deploy" Action="Deploy" Verb="Process">
            <Steps>
                <Step Id="SchemaDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                    <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.SchemaDeploy" Type="SchemaDeploy"/>
                </Step>
                <Step Id="PageDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                    <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageDeploy" Type="PageDeploy">
                        <Transformer Class="com.tridion.transformer.TCDLDefaultTransformer"/>
                    </Module>
                </Step>
                <Step Id="BinaryDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                    <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.BinaryDeploy" Type="BinaryDeploy"/>
                </Step>
                <Step Id="ComponentDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                    <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentDeploy" Type="ComponentDeploy"/>
                </Step>
                <Step Id="TemplateDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                    <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.TemplateDeploy" Type="TemplateDeploy"/>
                </Step>
                <Step Id="PublicationDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                    <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.PublicationDeploy" Type="PublicationDeploy"/>
                </Step>
                <Step Id="TaxonomyDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                    <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.TaxonomyDeploy" Type="TaxonomyDeploy"/>
                </Step>
                <Step Id="ComponentPresentationDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                    <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentPresentationDeploy" Type="ComponentPresentationDeploy">
                        <Transformer Class="com.tridion.transformer.TCDLDefaultTransformer"/>
                    </Module>
                </Step>
                <Step Id="StructureGroupDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                    <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.StructureGroupDeploy" Type="StructureGroupDeploy"/>
                </Step>
            </Steps>
        </Pipeline>
        <Pipeline Id="Tridion-Process-Undeploy" Action="Undeploy" Verb="Process">
            <Steps>
                <Step Id="PageUndeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                    <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageUndeploy" Type="PageUndeploy"/>
                </Step>
                <Step Id="ComponentPresentationUndeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                    <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentPresentationUndeploy" Type="ComponentPresentationUndeploy"/>
                </Step>
                <Step Id="TaxonomyUndeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                    <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.TaxonomyUndeploy" Type="TaxonomyUndeploy"/>
                </Step>
                <Step Id="StructureGroupUndeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                    <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.StructureGroupUndeploy" Type="StructureGroupUndeploy"/>
                </Step>
            </Steps>
        </Pipeline>
        <Pipeline Id="Tridion-PreCommit-TX" Action="Deploy,Undeploy" Verb="PreCommit">
            <Steps>
                <Step Id="TridionPreCommitStep"/>
            </Steps>
        </Pipeline>
        <Pipeline Id="Tridion-Commit-TX" Action="Deploy,Undeploy" Verb="Commit">
            <Steps>
                <Step Id="TridionCommitStep">
                    <RetryPoint PipelineId="Tridion-PreCommit-TX" StepId="TridionPreCommitStep"/>
                </Step>
            </Steps>
        </Pipeline>
        <Pipeline Id="Tridion-Rollback-TX" Action="Deploy,Undeploy" Verb="Rollback">
            <Steps>
                <Step Id="TridionRollbackStep"/>
            </Steps>
        </Pipeline>
        <Pipeline Id="Tridion-Cleanup" Action="Deploy,Undeploy" Verb="*">
            <Steps>
                <Step Id="TridionCleanupStep"/>
            </Steps>
        </Pipeline>
    </Pipelines>
    <BinaryStorage Id="PackageStorage" Adapter="FileSystem">
        <Property Name="Path" Value="C:\SDL\Web\service_folder\binary"/>
    </BinaryStorage>
    <State>
        <Storage Adapter="mssql" driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver">
            <Property Name="host" Value="localhost"/>
            <Property Name="port" Value="1433"/>
            <Property Name="database" Value="Tridion_Broker"/>
            <Property Name="user" Value="TridionBrokerUser"/>
            <Property Name="password" Value="*****"/>
        </Storage>
    </State>
    <Queues>
        <Queue Default="true" Verbs="Content" Adapter="FileSystem" Id="ContentQueue">
            <Property Name="Destination" Value="C:\SDL\Web\service_folder\queue\incoming"/>
        </Queue>
        <Queue Verbs="Commit,Rollback" Adapter="FileSystem" Id="CommitQueue">
            <Property Name="Destination" Value="C:\SDL\Web\service_folder\queue\incoming\FinalTX"/>
        </Queue>
        <Queue Verbs="Prepare" Adapter="FileSystem" Id="PrepareQueue">
            <Property Name="Destination" Value="C:\SDL\Web\service_folder\queue\incoming\Prepare"/>
        </Queue>
        <Adapter Id="FileSystem">
            <Property Name="LocationPollingInterval" Value="2s"/> 
        </Adapter>
        <Workers>
            <Property Name="QueuePollingInterval" Value="2s"/>
            <Property Name="RetriesInterval" Value="100ms"/>
            <Property Name="MaxRetries" Value="11"/>
            <Property Name="Cleanup" Value="true"/> 
        </Workers>
    </Queues>
    <License Path="C:\SDL\Web\cd_licenses.xml"/>
</Deployer>
```

- Last Portion of Deployer log below (unable to attch the full log because of char limitation)

> 2017-07-14 01:43:46,034 DEBUG QueueUtil - Using queue: ContentQueue for verb: Content for command: JSONCommand{verbs=[Content], action='TridionBootstrap', binaryIds=[tcm_0-2006-66560.Content.zip], executionId='tcm:0-2006-66560', properties={}} 
>   2017-07-14 01:43:46,034 DEBUG FSDeployerQueue - Queue [Id=ContentQueue]. Serializing command JSONCommand{verbs=[Content], action='TridionBootstrap', binaryIds=[tcm_0-2006-66560.Content.zip], executionId='tcm:0-2006-66560', properties={}} to 'C:\SDL\Web\service_folder\queue\incoming\ContentQueue\tcm_0-2006-66560.Content.json.busy'
>   2017-07-14 01:43:46,128 DEBUG JSONCommandSerializer - Command serialized '{"executionId":"tcm:0-2006-66560","verbs":["Content"],"action":"TridionBootstrap","binaryIds":["tcm_0-2006-66560.Content.zip"],"properties":{}}'
>   2017-07-14 01:43:46,144 DEBUG FSDeployerQueue - Queue [Id=ContentQueue]. Command JSONCommand{verbs=[Content], action='TridionBootstrap', binaryIds=[tcm_0-2006-66560.Content.zip], executionId='tcm:0-2006-66560', properties={}} serialized to 'C:\SDL\Web\service_folder\queue\incoming\ContentQueue\tcm_0-2006-66560.Content.json.busy'
>   2017-07-14 01:43:46,144 DEBUG FSDeployerQueue - Queue [Id=ContentQueue]. Command JSONCommand{verbs=[Content], action='TridionBootstrap', binaryIds=[tcm_0-2006-66560.Content.zip], executionId='tcm:0-2006-66560', properties={}} ready in 'C:\SDL\Web\service_folder\queue\incoming\ContentQueue\tcm_0-2006-66560.Content.json'
>   2017-07-14 01:43:46,488 INFO  FSLocationPoller - Found path: C:\SDL\Web\service_folder\queue\incoming\ContentQueue\tcm_0-2006-66560.Content.json
>   2017-07-14 01:43:46,488 DEBUG JSONCommandSerializer - Command de-serialized 'JSONCommand{verbs=[Content], action='TridionBootstrap', binaryIds=[tcm_0-2006-66560.Content.zip], executionId='tcm:0-2006-66560', properties={}}'
>   2017-07-14 01:43:46,488 INFO  FSDeployerQueue - Command for file 'C:\SDL\Web\service_folder\queue\incoming\ContentQueue\tcm_0-2006-66560.Content.json' and queue [Id=ContentQueue] de-serialized to JSONCommand{verbs=[Content], action='TridionBootstrap', binaryIds=[tcm_0-2006-66560.Content.zip], executionId='tcm:0-2006-66560', properties={}}
>   2017-07-14 02:33:14,775 DEBUG DeployerLegacyEndpointController - Retrieving list of files from storage: PackageStorage with extension.progress 
>   2017-07-14 02:33:14,907 DEBUG DeployerLegacyEndpointController - Retrieving list of files from storage: PackageStorage with extension.content.zip 
>   2017-07-14 02:33:15,084 DEBUG QueueUtil - Enqueue command for verb: Content
>   2017-07-14 02:33:15,085 DEBUG QueueUtil - Using queue: ContentQueue for verb: Content for command: JSONCommand{verbs=[Content], action='TridionBootstrap', binaryIds=[tcm_0-2008-66560.Content.zip], executionId='tcm:0-2008-66560', properties={}} 
>   2017-07-14 02:33:15,086 DEBUG FSDeployerQueue - Queue [Id=ContentQueue]. Serializing command JSONCommand{verbs=[Content], action='TridionBootstrap', binaryIds=[tcm_0-2008-66560.Content.zip], executionId='tcm:0-2008-66560', properties={}} to 'C:\SDL\Web\service_folder\queue\incoming\ContentQueue\tcm_0-2008-66560.Content.json.busy'
>   2017-07-14 02:33:15,097 DEBUG JSONCommandSerializer - Command serialized '{"executionId":"tcm:0-2008-66560","verbs":["Content"],"action":"TridionBootstrap","binaryIds":["tcm_0-2008-66560.Content.zip"],"properties":{}}'
>   2017-07-14 02:33:15,118 DEBUG FSDeployerQueue - Queue [Id=ContentQueue]. Command JSONCommand{verbs=[Content], action='TridionBootstrap', binaryIds=[tcm_0-2008-66560.Content.zip], executionId='tcm:0-2008-66560', properties={}} serialized to 'C:\SDL\Web\service_folder\queue\incoming\ContentQueue\tcm_0-2008-66560.Content.json.busy'
>   2017-07-14 02:33:15,120 DEBUG FSDeployerQueue - Queue [Id=ContentQueue]. Command JSONCommand{verbs=[Content], action='TridionBootstrap', binaryIds=[tcm_0-2008-66560.Content.zip], executionId='tcm:0-2008-66560', properties={}} ready in 'C:\SDL\Web\service_folder\queue\incoming\ContentQueue\tcm_0-2008-66560.Content.json'
>   2017-07-14 02:33:15,288 INFO  FSLocationPoller - Found path: C:\SDL\Web\service_folder\queue\incoming\ContentQueue\tcm_0-2008-66560.Content.json
>   2017-07-14 02:33:15,298 DEBUG JSONCommandSerializer - Command de-serialized 'JSONCommand{verbs=[Content], action='TridionBootstrap', binaryIds=[tcm_0-2008-66560.Content.zip], executionId='tcm:0-2008-66560', properties={}}'
>   2017-07-14 02:33:15,299 INFO  FSDeployerQueue - Command for file 'C:\SDL\Web\service_folder\queue\incoming\ContentQueue\tcm_0-2008-66560.Content.json' and queue [Id=ContentQueue] de-serialized to JSONCommand{verbs=[Content], action='TridionBootstrap', binaryIds=[tcm_0-2008-66560.Content.zip], executionId='tcm:0-2008-66560', properties={}}

Comment: I don't see any error in deployer log

Comment: clean you incoming queue folder & publish again and check if package is reaching at incoming folder, also check folder permissions.

Comment: @RajKumar I can see the transaction zip file is present at `C:\SDL\Web\service_folder\binary\Binaries\tcm_0-2008-66560.Content.zip` and I see a json file inside incoming folder (`C:\SDL\Web\service_folder\queue\incoming\ContentQueue\tcm_0-2008-66560.Content.json`). Seems like something is wrong with the `cd-deployer` config. Could you guide me please.

Comment: I tried cleaning the incoming folder many a times, no result.

Comment: Your log is in **Debug** mode and the error states the transaction is timing out (exceeding polling attempts), so maybe you should consider setting the log level back to error, clear the log and try a simple publish action again, so you can monitor the log for errors, rather than having it full with debug statements (debug logging is a huge strain on the system). Please **edit** your question after so you can update it with more relevant information (removing what isn't current anymore etc.)

Comment: In 8.5, we have two ways of setting up deployer - deployer-combined and split deployer (deployer service and deployer-worker service). Can you confirm which role you are using in this installation ? If using split deployer, then both deployer and deployer-worker service should be running and the configs should look similar (binary storage and queue configuration). http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-72AF9062-C687-427F-BE57-101DEB05A58F

Comment: In 8.5 CD, are you using deployer-combined or installed deployer and worker service separately? seems to be you only installed deployer

Comment: The logging output is for two distinct transactions, tcm:0-2006-66560 and tcm:0-2008-66560. I think your question would be clearer if you only showed logging for one transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Does the content publish eventually, if you wait long enough? The above could be just a warning, although not the most elegant way to put it.  Otherwise it could still be masking a different reason this is happening..

I would try extending the transaction polling timeout for the transport service, here is how (referenced from [this SDL Community article](https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=00262640)):

Increase polling in the transport configuration file, **(CMS)\SDL Web\config\cd_transport_conf.xml**

For instance, this is the default entry and the numbers may need to be raised via a tuning exercise.

```
<!-- Specifies the polling attempts and timeout in minutes and interval between polls in milliseconds -->
<Polling MaxAttempts="900" Timeout="15" Interval="5000"/>
```

This setting signifies the time interval between checks for feedback.

With the setup above, the poller will check every 5 seconds for the status of each transport package.

It will stop polling after 900 tries, or after the combination of attempts and interval which in this case is (900 x 5)/60 = 75 min ( 1 hr & 15 min), or after the assigned interval of 15 minutes.

**MaxAttempts** - The maximum number of polling attempts

**Interval** - the interval between polling attempts, in milliseconds

**Timeout** - the polling timeout period, in minutes

A transaction will be failed once the first of two limits is exceeded.

Comment: Good point. If it fails on the deployment side before your polling runs out, you'll see the failure reported back. When it says "exceeded polling attempts" the indication is that either 1) the deployer is still busy and has not yet failed, or 2) it's failed in some way that prevents it reporting failure back the CM.

Answer (score 0):

The process for publishing is:

1. Publisher Service creates ZIP package and places it in the incoming transport folder
2. Transport service picks it up and puts it in the incoming Deployer folder
3. Deployer service is listening on the folder, gets the transport package, and using the storage_conf settings, stores the content

I'd suggest to start with a fresh Deployer setup, and fresh set of config files.  Also, maybe put your transport service in info or debug mode and see the log messages.

You can find out more info on the publish status steps in the online documentation here:  http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web%20Cloud-v1/GUID-714ACA0C-264F-4C63-8C93-AFFDA95C3DA3